# Increase JDBC DataSource connection acquire time

Tags: java, jdbc

I get following error when accessing DB when JDBC connection pool is full.

```
Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 0 seconds, none available[size:5; busy:4; idle:0; lastwait:5]
```

It says it was unable to fetch a connection in 0 seconds. How can I increase the waiting time to fetch a connection (0 seconds in this case)?

I am using Tomcat datasource implementation.

Comment: Which connection pool implementation do you use? Also check that you really need that many connections (did you probably forget to close some?)

Comment: @Henry, updated the question.